# Why Pandas allows editing DataFrames but not Series objects

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataset like below : 
[image]

When I try to overwrite a specific column (Series object), I get the error with the following code :

```
mask = bond["Actor"] == "Sean Connery"
bond[mask]["Actor"] = "Sir Sean Connery"
```

But the moment I move one level down and instead edit all the columns of those rows (complete DataFrame), I succeed

```
mask = bond["Actor"] == "Sean Connery"
bond[mask] = "Sir Sean Connery"
```

Why is that so? In the first case, I thought that its not logical to edit a copy and hence the error. But the same should be applicable in the latter case also, as the second example should also return a copy of the original DataFrame.

Comment: @ayhan : Sorry still not clear. Why both the cases have different behaviour. I expect both of them to return reference of original DataFrame (rows or columns). For some reason, obviously first one returns a copy and not the original. What is that reason? Secondly, as per my understanding from this link http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy shared in the answer, `__getitem__` will be called twice in the first case, whereas only once in the second.

Comment: @ayhan : Or maybe you are right about call to `__getitem__` as I read the following paragraph on the same page http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing. Its difficult to digest for me. Looks like its not easy to predict whether one will get a view or a copy.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem you need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for avoid [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy):

```
bond = pd.DataFrame({'Actor':list('abcaef'),
                   'A':list('efghij'),
                   'B':list('aaabbb')})

print (bond)
   A Actor  B
0  e     a  a
1  f     b  a
2  g     c  a
3  h     a  b
4  i     e  b
5  j     f  b
```

---

```
mask = bond["Actor"] == "a"
bond.loc[mask] = "AAA"
#for select all columns :, for columns can be omitted
#bond.loc[mask,:] = "AAA"

print (bond)
     A Actor    B
0  AAA   AAA  AAA
1    f     b    a
2    g     c    a
3  AAA   AAA  AAA
4    i     e    b
5    j     f    b

#one column Actor
bond.loc[mask, "Actor"] = "AAA"
print (bond)
   A Actor  B
0  e   AAA  a
1  f     b  a
2  g     c  a
3  h   AAA  b
4  i     e  b
5  j     f  b
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following single column DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actor': ['Sean Connery', 'Sean Connery', 
                             'Sean Something', 'Sean Something Else']})

df
Out: 
                 Actor
0         Sean Connery
1         Sean Connery
2       Sean Something
3  Sean Something Else
```

And this is the mask that you want to use for slicing:

```
mask = df['Actor'] == 'Sean Connery'
```

Now, if I use `df[mask]['Actor'] = 'Sir Sean Connery'`, this will be executed:

```
df.__getitem__(mask).__setitem__('Actor', 'Sir Sean Connery')
```

> ```
> __main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
> ```
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

And for this case it will not modify the original DataFrame:

```
df
Out: 
                 Actor
0         Sean Connery
1         Sean Connery
2       Sean Something
3  Sean Something Else
```

Id *did* modify a DataFrame though - which was returned by the `__getitem__` method but since it was not assigned to anything, it is lost.

Instead, in your second example (`df[mask] = 'Sir Sean Connery'`) the code executed is:

```
df.__setitem__(mask, 'Sir Sean Connery')
```

Because of the mask you probably think it uses `__getitem__` too but it does not. It directly uses `__setitem__` and passes the mask to that DataFrame. And pandas ensures us that with `__setitem__` we can be sure that it will operate on a view. For the case of `__getitem__` it says it can be o copy or it can be a view - hard to know.

Now you'll see that the original df is modified:

```
df
Out: 
                 Actor
0     Sir Sean Connery
1     Sir Sean Connery
2       Sean Something
3  Sean Something Else
```

There is one catch though. It worked because we only had one column. If we had another column, say 'Year', it would set the corresponding Year values to 'Sir Sean Connery' too. In order to avoid that, we use `.loc` as jezrael pointed out. It also calls the `__setitem__` method and allows specifying which columns will change.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actor': ['Sean Connery', 'Sean Connery', 
                             'Sean Something', 'Sean Something Else'],
                  'Year': [1990, 1990, 1990, 1990]})


df.loc.__setitem__((mask, 'Actor'), 'Sir Sean Connery')

df
Out: 
                 Actor  Year
0     Sir Sean Connery  1990
1     Sir Sean Connery  1990
2       Sean Something  1990
3  Sean Something Else  1990
```

As a result, best practice to set based on a mask and column name(s) is to use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[mask, 'Actor'] = 'Sir Sean Connery'
```

This way you don't have to worry if you are operating on a copy.